# Caption above figure?

Tags: floats, captions

I would like to show a caption above a figure. 
I looked around for some solutions, but I still can not achieve my goal.

This is my code:

```
   \documentclass[12]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xpatch} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
.
.
.
\end{titlepage}
.
.
.
 \begin{table} [H]
                \caption{Summary of the Proctor compaction test results.}
                 \includegraphics[scale=0.80]{Excel_table.png}
    \end{table}

\end {document}
```

However, the caption still displays below the graphics. Can someone please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: the default is for the caption to appear exactly where you place `\caption` so if it is appearing below the figure you (or your class file) must have specified that but you have shown no relevant code so it is hard to help

Comment: Hi David, I have included the packages I am using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

binary chop on your package list soon shows that this is a feature of `floatrow` if you do not include that package, the caption is above the image.

```
\documentclass[12]{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}




%\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}


 \begin{table} [H]
                \caption{Summary of the Proctor compaction test results.}
                 \includegraphics[scale=0.80]{example-image}
    \end{table}

\end {document}
```

Comment: Wow thank you that fixed it. What would the package floatrow be used for?

Comment: you might want to look at `texdoc floatrow` and the rawcaption command which looks like a way to escape the packages caption logic

Comment: @CivilSigma er if you don't know why have you loaded it??? It's a really bad idea to load lots of packages you don't use them: it slows things down and leads to unnecessary conflicts (`floatrow` is for controlling float and caption positioning.....)

Comment: Yea it is a bad practice, but I find it hard to memorize all the different packages and their uses - so I always compile the same list of packages I use to compose my documents.

Comment: @CivilSigma I often add a comment line behind a package to remind myself why I included the package. Especially in my early LaTeX days.

Comment: @Rolad That is a good approach! Didn't strike me to do that... Thanks